# Second-to-last measure (m. 33) of Chopin Op 9 No 2

Tags: rhythm, beats, beaming

The second-to-last measure of Chopin's Op.9 No.2 has two voices(?). The very first double note (G-Eb2) on right hand, how do you tell which is that "other voice" and which one goes with the two other notes (Bb-G2) on the same beam? Also it seems to me from the score that the G and Eb2 are both 1/8 and so have the same duration, however I see multiple people playing it by holding down the G (with the thumb) while playing the Eb2 *and* the Bb (second note), why?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three reasonable interpretations for the "other voice":

1. There really isn't a second voice in the right hand, or, the second voice comes and goes. On piano there is some leeway in terms of interpreting voices; they can come and go within the music. In a multi-instrument piece this would sound weird, with instruments entering and exiting at odd moments, but on piano it's usually not disruptive.
2. After the G-Eb dyad, both voices "sing" the Bb and Eb. This is how I think of it. Double-stemming would just create clutter, so it's left off, but aurally it makes sense that these are two overlapping triplets.
3. The right-hand G4 and the left-hand Bb3 are the middle voice. The argument here would be that the G4 is one eighth note, and the Bb3 is a quarter note (i.e., two eighth notes), thus making a complete triplet beat. This is the weakest interpretation, I think, because they don't really sound like a single voice, and were that the intention, the beaming would almost surely reflect that.

As to why some pianists hold down the G, it's probably just convenience or comfort. Since the pedal is used throughout, it's not going to change the sound if the G4 is held an extra eighth note.

Comment: My Henle edition doesn't have the upper stem of the Bb notes on the bass clef. (the image is from a video)